# Error while deploy with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I tried to build a project with GCE (Google cloud engine) and I'm having a few problems...

I followed their orders step by step but every time i bump into the same problem.

I used this guide: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Every thing is fine until the first step of GCE, when i need to "Deploy the app to Google Cloud Platform",

I run the command "gcloud preview app deploy", it ask me to press "Y" and after few secondes it writes: "
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair." 
and get stuck in this step....

I copied the proccess:

```
>gcloud preview app deploy
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - **Project-ID**/default (from [D:\User\Downloads\nodejs-getting-started\1-hello-world\app.yaml])
 Deployed URL: []

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment...
If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.

Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
Provisioning remote build service.
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
```

I tried to press enter a few times but it returns:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unable to copy certificates.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you check if your CloudSDK is recent version (you can run ```gcloud components update``` to update to most recent version) and make sure you're the owner of the project in Developer Console? If this doesn't help, please run the ```gcloud preview app deploy``` with either ```--noisy``` or ```-v``` to raise the log level and update the question with output

Comment: Can you try `gcloud auth login` command to login with your project owner account and try to deploy again?

Comment: @Kamran Didn't help...

Comment: @VadimSolovey "gcloud components update" didn't help..
Where do I put the flag?

Comment: @OhadShapira Sorry, please run this ```gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy```

Comment: @VadimSolovey

INFO: Display disabled.
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'compute', 'copy_files']

DEBUG: Error copying certificates. Retry 0 of 20.

DEBUG: Error copying certificates. Retry 1 of 20.


and goes like this....

Comment: @Ohad Shapira, seems this is a bug which has been already reported on this [public tracking issue.](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=529). A workaround is mentioned in the same link.

Comment: @Kamran It didn't helped me but thank you!

The result of the workaround was this
`DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'compute', 'copy_files']
DEBUG: Error copying certificates. Retry 0 of 20.
y
DEBUG: Error copying certificates. Retry 1 of 20.
.
.
.
DEBUG: Error copying certificates. Retry 19 of 20.
DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unable to copy certificates.
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 646, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)

ToolException: Unable to copy certificates.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unable to copy certificates.`

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `gcloud info` command. please feel free to remove/exclude the information about your project from the post.

Comment: @Kamran
`Google Cloud SDK [96.0.0]

Platform: [Windows, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]]
Python Location: [C:\python27\python.exe]
Site Packages: [Disabled]`

Comment: @OhadShapira, this issue have been fixed in latest version of [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). Please update your SDK, try again and let me know if it not resolve your issue or you see any different issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=529

Comment: @Kamran As you can see i posted my new exception in the comments of the link that you gave me. It didn't halped much...

Comment: @OhadShapira, based on your comment of yesterday, I can see that you're using `Google Cloud SDK [96.0.0]`. We just released Google Cloud SDK 97.0.0. If you have not tried this latest release, please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SDK 97.0.0 fixed the problem, they had a little bug.

Thank you all!